# 85 bit encoded strings are not being handled correctly on being decoded in python

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, pyspark

I have encoded a hexadecimal (Device Id):

```
9F1D8E8BA2194CD29CC744083914535A
```

Into an 85 bit encoded number (Equivalent Conversion):

```
T,irMU)?YQSB"#\'3>>Cq
```

These all are stored in spark dataframe.

The problem is when I try converting it back (passing the column to UDF) it doesn't give me the Device Id back, on debugging I found out that what output it gives is actually for:

```
T,irMU)?YQSB"#\\\'3>>Cq
```

Which means that actual string is adding an escape character automatically and then decoding it.

This is udf, I wrote for conversion:

```
def convert_id(id):
    id = id.replace("-", "")
    return str(bs64.a85encode(bytearray.fromhex(id)))[2:-1]

udf_convert_id = udf(convert_id, StringType())
```

This is for decoding it:

```
def convert_docid2idfa(docId):
    try:
        docId = docId.replace('\\\\','\\')
        id_str = bs64.a85decode(docId).hex()
        idfa = id_str[:8]+"-"+id_str[8:12]+"-"+id_str[12:16]+"-"+id_str[16:20]+"-"+id_str[20:]
        return idfa
    except:
        return docId

convert_docid2idfa_udf = udf(convert_docid2idfa, StringType())
```

And I am decoding this version, which has escape.

Comment: Can you share us your code? The actual Ascii85 encoded value is `T,irMU)?YQSB"#'3>>Cq` (no escapes), but the Python *representation* of that string uses `'T,irMU)?YQSB"#\'3>>Cq'` so you can copy and paste that value into another interpreter and have the embedded `'` value work with the `'...'` string delimiters used. If you sent the `str()` or `repr()` conversion over in the dataframe then you'd be decoding that conversion, not the original value.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that additional information.

Comment: And the solution is simple: don't use `str()`, you *already have as bytestring*. **Decode** bytestrings to `str`.

Comment: Data Frame displays me the string 'T,irMU)?YQSB"#\'3>>Cq' in the column.
I pass this string to my convert_docid2idfa_udf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *actual* value of the ASCII85 encoded ID should be:

```
T,irMU)?YQSB"#'3>>Cq
```

There should not be a `\` in the value. At fault is your conversion of the `a85encode()` result to a string:

```
str(bs64.a85encode(bytearray.fromhex(id)))[2:-1]
```

`a85encode()` returns a `bytes` object, you would need to **decode** that, as ASCII, to get a string value with the same codepoints:

```
bs64.a85encode(bytearray.fromhex(id)).decode('ASCII')
```

`str(bytesobject)` gives you a debug-friendly *representation* that is safe to paste back into Python code, so any `'` characters are escaped with a `\` in front. You do not want to use this representation for serialisation.

Note that you don't need a `bytearray`, a regular immutable `bytes` object is enough to decode the hex ID to a binary string:

```
bs64.a85encode(bytes.fromhex(id)).decode('ASCII')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import base64 as b64
>>> id = '9F1D8E8BA2194CD29CC744083914535A'
>>> encoded = bs64.a85encode(bytes.fromhex(id)).decode('ASCII')
>>> print(encoded)
T,irMU)?YQSB"#'3>>Cq
>>> b64.a85decode(encoded).hex()
'9f1d8e8ba2194cd29cc744083914535a'
```

If you can't repair the encoding you can still repair the broken values by using the `unicode_escape` codec; encode the string to ASCII first. You should be able to detect such a broken value by testing the length, a 20-byte IDFA should always result in a 20-character ASCII85 string, anything longer needs repairing:

```
if len(docId) > 20:
    docId = docId.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape')
decoded = b64.a85decode(docId).hex()
```

The above repairs the escapes introduced by calling `str()` on a bytes object:

```
>>> encoded
'T,irMU)?YQSB"#\'3>>Cq'
>>> botched = str(encoded.encode('ascii'))[2:-1]
>>> botched
'T,irMU)?YQSB"#\\\'3>>Cq'
>>> botched.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape')
'T,irMU)?YQSB"#\'3>>Cq'
>>> bs64.a85decode(botched.encode('ascii').decode('unicode_escape')).hex()
'9f1d8e8ba2194cd29cc744083914535a'
```

Note that if you are working with IDFA values, you can use the [`uuid.UUID()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID) to convert between representations:

```
from uuid import UUID

bs64.a85encode(UUID(hex=id).bytes).decode('ASCII')
```

to encode, and

```
str(UUID(bytes=bs64.a85decode(docId)))
```

to go back to the 8-4-4-4-12 hex string with dashes:

```
>>> from uuid import UUID
>>> id = '9F1D8E8B-A219-4CD2-9CC7-44083914535A'
>>> encoded = bs64.a85encode(UUID(hex=id).bytes).decode('ASCII')
>>> encoded
'T,irMU)?YQSB"#\'3>>Cq'
>>> str(UUID(bytes=bs64.a85decode(encoded)))
'9f1d8e8b-a219-4cd2-9cc7-44083914535a'
```

Comment: Since the damage is done already to the encoding which is already in production, is there anyway I can actually make my decode work properly? Considering I cant modify the encoding.

Comment: @NiteshGupta: oh dear.. Yes, you can, by decoding as Unicode escapes. I'll add that.

Comment: Awesome Thanks.